# JSON undefined error at position 1 when trying to define a function

Tags: javascript, json, plugins, minecraft

I am writing a bit for a minecraft skript plugin. Trying to define a function that makes text the correct case. When I define the function, I get an error at position 1. It says:

> ```
> Error: Parse error on line 1:  
> function uppercase(t  
> ^  
> Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got             'undefined'
> ```

Could anyone help me solving this? Other code can be provided if necessary.

Comment: Please make a little  snippet with your problem, so we can debug better.

Answer (score 1):

JSON files are *data.*  They cannot contain functions.

The only valid things you can put int a json file are strings (`"this is a string"`), numbers (`1`), null (`null`), booleans (`TRUE`), and object or array declarations (`{}` and `[]` respectively) which contain any further valid json objects separated by commas.

Answer (score 0):

This *might* be a very stupid error of the BOM variety. Make sure your file is saved as UTF-8 *without BOM*. If your file is saved as UTF-8 with BOM, some interpreters will read the BOM as the first character of the code. Since the character is unprintable, it will not show in the error message, marking an error that is completely unintelligible.

Please comment if it's the case, if not, I will remove the answer.